# Are there certain actions to take to prevent an "Unable to load OpenGL library" error in Python?

Tags: python, macos, opengl, manim

I'm trying to get into using the manim software of 3b1b but have many issues.

First after completing the steps of installing the required software given on the Youtube channel "Theorem of Beethoven" I still get the following error when trying to load the manimlib function.

```
ImportError: ('Unable to load OpenGL library', 'dlopen(OpenGL, 10): image not found', 'OpenGL', None)
```

The code I ran is: `from manimlib.imports import *`. What needs to be done to remove this error? Also, in what directory do I need to be in order to run the manim code on VS Code?

Answer (score 0):

I think the resources you are using are outdated now.
`from manimlib.imports import*` was used in earlier versions of Manim.
Click [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Upztg_Bs-zs&t=652s) to find Theorem of Beethoven's 2021 3b1b Manim installation tutorial.

In the case I am wrong or misunderstood your question, try [this file](https://github.com/3b1b/manim/blob/master/example_scenes.py) from 3b1b Manim github and see if it works.

Also, I recommend you take a look at [Manim Community](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/) because it has more documentation. Manim Community is maintained by volunteers.